# Issue with Jenkins, rake on new windows 7 machine

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rake

We have setup a new Windows 7 machine as Jenkins slave. We use rake to execute the tasks in parallel. Execution with rake has been tested successfully with Jenkins on other windows 7 machines but it is giving error with this new machine. Error is as below:-

> [Test1] $ rake.bat parallel_IE
>   ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- C:/Slave/workspace/Test1/rake (LoadError)

Please consider below points:-

1. The tests executes successfully through IntelliJ (without Jenkins)
2. The ruby bin directory has correctly been specified in 'Path'
3. In the workspace on this new machine Rakefile.rb is at present at correct path
4. rake gem is installed on this machine

Could anyone please help in resolving this issue?

Thanks,
Divya

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the rake task from the command line?